# How to get access to controls from CB when using hub - Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, code-behind

I'm writing app in Windows Phone 8.1 and
I want to get access to controls from Code-Behind.

Normally everything works great but when I use hub I don't have access to fields from Code-Behind.

```
<Hub x:Name="RHub">
        <HubSection>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                   <TextBox x:Name="Test5"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
        <HubSection>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
</Hub>
```

And now in Code-Behind file is no such field like Test5, only RHub.

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/a/26801276/734040](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26801276/734040).

Answer (score 0):

This is because the control is inside a DataTemplate. One easy way to get around this limitation is to hook into the Element Loaded-event. Here’s the XAML:

```
<HubSection Header="Trailers">
    <DataTemplate>
        <ListView x:Name="MovieTrailers" Loaded="MovieTrailers_Loaded">

        </ListView>
    </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

And the code-behind:

```
private void MovieTrailers_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var listView = (ListView)sender;
    listView.ItemsSource = trailers;
}
```

if you want to search any element in the list view you can use a method like:

```
public static DependencyObject FindChildControl<T>(DependencyObject control, string ctrlName)
{
    int childNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);


    for (int i = 0; i < childNumber; i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, i);
        FrameworkElement fe = child as FrameworkElement;
        // Not a framework element or is null
        if (fe == null) return null;

        if (child is T && fe.Name == ctrlName)
        {
            // Found the control so return
            Debug.WriteLine("Achou");
            return child;
        }
        else
        {
            // Not found it - search children
            DependencyObject nextLevel = FindChildControl<T>(child, ctrlName);
            if (nextLevel != null)
                return nextLevel;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and search:

```
private void findRectangle(ListView listView)
{
    Rectangle ret = this.FindChildControl<Rectangle>(listView, "ret1") as Rectangle;
    if(ret != null)
    {
        ret.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(this.color);
    }
}
```