# How to Access Grid View from hub section Data Template Windows phone 8.1 in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Please tell me how i can assess the grid view in the hub section data template.
In universal app ( Windows Phone 8.1 )
Following is the xaml

```
   <HubSection Header="English Newspapers" x:Name="HubEnglish">
        <DataTemplate x:Name="DTEnglish">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <GridView x:Name="LstEnglishNewspapers">
                        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">

                                    <Image x:Name="txtNewspaperImage" Source="{Binding PicPath}" Height="60" Width="60" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtNewspaperHeader" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="14.667" FontWeight="Light" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtNewsHeader" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="14.667" FontWeight="Light" Width="200" MaxHeight="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                    </StackPanel>

                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>

                        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    </GridView>

                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

    </HubSection>
```

I have tried using this code to get the grid but im getting exception.

```
var grid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(HubEnglish.ContentTemplate, 0);
```

Exception : Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

Comment: well it would help to show what the exception is that you are getting as well.. don't you think..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE i have updated the question with exception. Please have a look

Comment: have you looked at the following [VisualTreeHelper.GetChild() Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.getchild.aspx)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26801276/734040).

Comment: is there any other solution

Comment: Got Some idea from this [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800032/windows-phone-8-1-toggling-the-visibility-of-a-textblock-in-a-datatemplate/26801276#26801276) in order to get the data template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this code in order to get the data template

```
    static DependencyObject FindChildByName(DependencyObject from, string name)
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(from);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(from, i);
        if (child is FrameworkElement && ((FrameworkElement)child).Name == name)
            return child;

        var result = FindChildByName(child, name);
        if (result != null)
            return result;
    }

    return null;
}

private TextBlock NoArticlesTextBlock;

private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Note: No need to start searching from the root (this), we can just start
    // from the relevant HubSection or whatever. Make sure your TextBlock has
    // x:Name="NoArticlesTextBlock" attribute in the XAML.
    NoArticlesTextBlock = (TextBlock)FindChildByName(this, "NoArticlesTextBlock");
}
```