# How to access hub section control in c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

```
<Hub x:Name="Hub" x:Uid="Hub" Header="Clock +" Background="Black"  

SectionsInViewChanged="Hub_SectionsInViewChanged">




        <HubSection Tag="0" Name="WorldClock" x:Uid="WorldClock" Header="WORLD CLOCK" 
                    DataContext="{Binding Groups}" HeaderTemplate="{ThemeResource HubSectionHeaderTemplate}" FontSize="22" >
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />

                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" 
                       Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       Text="" x:Name="date_time_block"/>

                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>

        </HubSection>
```

my main concern is that in the above code there is textblock I want to know how to access that textblock in c#. I know c# but a little knew to XAML.If I put textblock outside hub section it is accessible but when I put inside hub section it is not Please help!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8.1 Toggling the visibility of a TextBlock in a DataTemplate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800032/windows-phone-8-1-toggling-the-visibility-of-a-textblock-in-a-datatemplate)

Comment: You can find the answer in the question I marked as duplicate.