# How do i access a control within a hub section data template windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Ok I have been working on an app for awhile now this is my first windows phone app I have made and I have been running into a problem. The way I designed my app is my start page is a hub control and I have two textboxs and a date picker on each page and some other controls. Now what I want to do is when I press the add button on a given section then I want to take all the strings from my various controls and add it to a textfile that I will later use. My problem is when I make the event for the button I cannot access the controls because they are inside the hubs data template. I have looked a many other examples on how to get around this they just dont seem to work and I cant make sense of them. So if anyone on here has the patience to kinda step me through the process that would be wonderful. Thank you for any help.

```
<Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="85,7,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text=":" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="21.333"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tbHours" LostFocus="tbHours_LostFocus" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" InputScope="Number" PlaceholderText="   hrs" Width="80"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tbMinutes" LostFocus="tbMinutes_LostFocus" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="95,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" InputScope="Number" PlaceholderText="   min" Width="80"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,50,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Work date" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14.667"/>
                <DatePicker LostFocus="DatePicker_LostFocus" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="127"/>
                <AppBarButton x:Name="abtnAddHours" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Icon="Add" Label="" Margin="118,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="abtnAddHours_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate2">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,7,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="$" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="21.333"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tbExpenses" LostFocus="tbExpenses_LostFocus" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" InputScope="Number" PlaceholderText="   0.00" Width="100"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,45,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Expense date" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14.667"/>
                <DatePicker x:Name="dtpkrExpenses" LostFocus="dtpkrExpenses_LostFocus" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,115,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Expense notes" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14.667"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tbNotes" LostFocus="tbNotes_LostFocus" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,140,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
                <AppBarButton x:Name="abtnAddExpense" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Icon="Add" Label="" Margin="193,128,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate3">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14.667" Text="Working hour rate" Height="20"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,32,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="21.333" Text="$"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="tbWage" LostFocus="tbWage_LostFocus" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,25,237,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" InputScope="Number" PlaceholderText="   0.00" Width="89"/>
                <AppBarButton x:Name="abtnAddWage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Icon="Add" Label="" Margin="92,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar ClosedDisplayMode="Compact">
            <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
                <AppBarButton Label="Reset"/>
            </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="abtnSummary" Icon="List" Label="Summary" Click="abtnSummary_Click"/>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>

    <Grid>
        <Hub x:Name="Hub" Header="Hours+" Background="{ThemeResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
            <HubSection x:Name="sctnAddHours" Header="Add hours" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1}"/>
            <HubSection x:Name="sctnAddExpenses" Header="Add expenses" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate2}"/>
            <HubSection x:Name="sctnWage" Header="Wage" Height="580" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate3}"/>
        </Hub>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: Add some code to your question...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8.1 Toggling the visibility of a TextBlock in a DataTemplate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800032/windows-phone-8-1-toggling-the-visibility-of-a-textblock-in-a-datatemplate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Loaded event of the control you want to access and assign it to a local variable like this.

XAML

```
<AppBarButton x:Name="abtnAddHours" Loaded="abtnAddHours_Loaded" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Icon="Add" Label="" Margin="118,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Code Behind

```
//local variable
private TextBlock _abtnAddHours;
//Loaded event of the TextBlock from the template
private void abtnAddHours_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _abtnAddHours = (TextBlock)sender;
    //Add the event handler for the Click event
    _abtnAddHours.Click += _abtnAddHours_Click;
}

private void _abtnAddHours_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Put your logic here
}
```