# Binding Text to Textbox in HubSection

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, win-universal-app

This question is similar to [Windows Phone 8.1 Toggling the visibility of a TextBlock in a DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800032/windows-phone-8-1-toggling-the-visibility-of-a-textblock-in-a-datatemplate)

and countless others, but none of these ideas are working. The Loaded event is never triggered after I add my Textblock to my datatemplate in my hub. The Visual Tree search is not finding my TextBlock.

I have tried a basic binding like this:

```
            <HubSection Background="{StaticResource HubSectionBackgroundBrush}"
                        MaxWidth="{x:Bind DesiredHubSectionWidth, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Header="You have selected:" Padding="60" 
                        >
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Scenario4">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Item}"/>
                </DataTemplate> 
            </HubSection>
```

with

```
public string Item { get; set; }
Item = makeText.Text;
```

But this doesn't work (Text on the Hub is always empty). From looking at previous posts and code I have come up with this xaml code using Dependency Properties:

```
             <HubSection Background="{StaticResource HubSectionBackgroundBrush}"
                        MaxWidth="{x:Bind DesiredHubSectionWidth, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Header="You have selected:" Padding="60"
                        >
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Scenario4">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{x:Bind DesiredSelectionText, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate> 
            </HubSection>
```

with this in the c#

```
    private static DependencyProperty s_desiredHubSectionWidthProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register("DesiredHubSectionWidth", typeof(double), typeof(Scenario4), new PropertyMetadata(560.0));

    private static DependencyProperty selectionText = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectionText", typeof(string), typeof(Scenario4), new PropertyMetadata("Nothing"));

    public static DependencyProperty DesiredHubSectionWidthProperty
    {
        get { return s_desiredHubSectionWidthProperty; }
    }

    public static DependencyProperty DesiredSelectionTextProperty
    {
        get { return selectionText; }
    }

    public string DesiredSelectionText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(selectionText); }
        set { SetValue(selectionText, value); }
    }

    public double DesiredHubSectionWidth
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(s_desiredHubSectionWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(s_desiredHubSectionWidthProperty, value); }
    }
```

and I set the text with

```
DesiredSelectionText = makeText.Text;
```

The width binding works perfectly, but the text is not updating. What is the proper way to change Hub/DataTemplate Text at Runtime? Since the Hub is not even printing "Nothing", something must be really wrong.

As a last resort I am thinking I will just construct my own datatemplate and assign it at runtime, but the only code I can find for that is deprecated(uses FrameworkElementFactory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to assign to the textblock in the *OnNavigatedTo* method which is called before the textblock's *Loaded* method. That's why my program was showing the textblock as null.

Turns out the link I posted is the solution, just for me, the textblock was loaded after the page was navigated to.