# Gridview Item dynamic width according to Screen Size in UWP

Tags: xaml, gridview, uwp, windows-10, visualstatemanager

I have created a GridView which gets data through data binding. What I want to do next is make the GridView item width dynamic according to the Screen Size (**Like the ones they have done in the Windows 10 news, sports app, etc.**) So far I have done it successfully for minimum window width 0 using visual state manager by setting the horizontal alignment to stretch, but I am not being able to continue this for other wider window sizes.

Any kind of help for sorting this out will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with adaptive triggers for the visual states? What exactly have you tried so far and what isn't working for you?

Comment: Yes, I have used adaptive trigger for the visual states setting the minWindowWidth to 800. I have used the setter property in the same to set the item MinWidth to 300 which is working. But what i want to do is dynamically make the width of the item change according to the window size of our app from window width 800 and onwards. The basic problem I am facing is that since i am defining the width in the setter property, it is no longer dynamic. How do i fix this problem ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the items to stretch to fill the horizontal space *and* be able to specify how many items per row you want, then you'll have to set the ItemWidth of the ItemsWrapGrid manually within the GridView's SizeChanged event.

Here's an example:

```
<GridView x:Name="gridView" SizeChanged="onGridViewSizeChanged">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="GreenYellow" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>

    <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>

    <x:String>1</x:String>
    <x:String>2</x:String>
    <x:String>3</x:String>
    <x:String>4</x:String>
    <x:String>5</x:String>
    <x:String>6</x:String>
    <x:String>7</x:String>
    <x:String>8</x:String>
</GridView>
```

```
private void onGridViewSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Here I'm calculating the number of columns I want based on
    // the width of the page
    var columns = Math.Ceiling(ActualWidth / 300);
    ((ItemsWrapGrid)gridView.ItemsPanelRoot).ItemWidth = e.NewSize.Width / columns;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

You could probably bundle this into a Behavior or attached property too.

Comment: oohhh man this is beautiful !! exactly what i wanted.. Although a slight problem still exists :( :(  My gridview is contained inside a pivot control which binds to a data. As a result i am not able to access the gridview from the code behind. Is using a visual tree the only way to solve this problem ??

Comment: You'll need to get a reference to the GridView via other means. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26801276/734040